# How to retrieve the output of a .Net project without the dependencies

Tags: .net

When one builds a .Net project, the output is copied into an output folder (e.g.: the bin folder); Not only the binaries issued from the project's source code are copied, but also all the dependencies (file references) marked with the option CopyLocal=True.

For the purpose of a custom Build task (i.e.: when compiling on Team Build) I would like to know how get the list of binaries issued from a build without those dependencies (I may not -  and don't want anyway - to set CopyLocal=False).

My issue is that I didn't find a clean way to determined this output. The closest solution I have is to loop on the project files, read the AssemblyName and check if there are pdb, xml, resx files foreseen. But still, I am sometimes missing resource files (?) and maybe other outputs as I don't know all the possible items.

So my question is: do you know any methods/tricks/algorithms to get the list of binaries issued by a Build; i.e. assemblies, satellite assemblies (+ path of their subfolders), pbd, xml (i.e.: documentation) but without the dependencies ?

Comment: It is really important to not require an answer to this question.

Comment: Setting **CopyLocal** to false is the solution.  You do understand without the dependencies in the local directory then your application is unlikely to run right?

Comment: Sorry but I may not set CopyLocal=False otherwise I don't have the dependencies available in the bin folder and cannot run the unit test on Team Build. Those are not in the GAC but on a Drop folder. In addition, I have better not modify the source. I am only managing the Build Server and not responsible/accountable for the source code. If there is no other clean way to determine the exact output, I could parse the project files and update the CopyLocal, but I don't know if there is an option for MSTest (like the "referencepath" option of MSBuild) to pass ot the Drop folder to MSTest

Comment: Said with other words, I try to find programmatically the "Primary output" and the "Content Files". Obviously MS does it at least for the "Setup Projects" where we can "reference" Primary Output, Localized Resources, Content Files and Documentation Files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a (maybe a really stupid) idea...

What about using the FileListAbsolute.txt generated in the "obj" folder during the build (on Team Build)? It precisely contains the output (dll, resx, xml, ...) of the build, without the dependencies. I can easily retreive it using Build Environment variables (path, etc...) and loop on it to get the names of the files dropped from the "obj" folder into the "bin" folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to all your assembly's post build events :

```
copy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).???" "C:\TargetDir"
```

You'll get your assembly in c:\TargetDir

Comment: Yes, But I will be missing some satellite assemblies (issued from resx) and the xml documentation (if this one is generated).

Comment: your resx are inside the dll, and for your xml documentation you can add "copy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).dll.XML" "C:\TargetDir""

Comment: Not all the resx are inside the dll! Your forget IMO the satellite assemblies

Comment: you can replace ".dll" with ".???" this will move all the resulting assemblies/pdb/xml

Comment: It would be a "quick and dirty solution" IMO and not working as-is for the satellite assemblies which are dropped into a subfolder depending on the culture and are named like this: "<culture>\<assemblyname>.resources.dll". My concern is also that I would like to rely on an official "process" to determine the output. What if MS add some new output with a Visual Studio SP or anything else ?

Comment: This is not a dirty solution, I didn't say replace "???" with what you want, but copy/paste my solution and you'll have what you're looking for, we do it for subversionning our company assemblies. Try it.

Comment: Sorry; by quick and dirty I meant a pragmatic and working solution but unfortunatelly not based on well defined rules/algorithms. Notice that IMO ".???" only means "anything matching the TargetName + an extension of exactely 3 characters". This wouldn't match any satellite assemblies in a subfolder (like fr/, nl/, nl-be/, fr-be/) under the bin folder. So I would have to implement a more complex script without having an well known rule to localize the files - I.e.: I won't have any formal information (environment variables) about the location where satellites assemblies are stored (Do I have ?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6584/discussion-between-valery-letroye-and-remi-bourgarel)